# Pandas - plot every single column of a Dataframe in a small multiple chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, charts

I have a dataset with 35 features. I want to plot every feature in a small multiple chart type, as this:

[image: example]

Now, I am able to plot features one by one with the following code:

```
# libraries and data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Make a data frame
df=pd.read_csv("mydataset.csv")
df.plot(y="feature1")
```

How can I achieve the result shown in the previous image ? I need something similar to:

```
# read the data in a Dataframe object
# for each feature (column):
#   plot the feature in the final small multiple chart
# render the full final chart
```

Thank you !

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_facets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the comment provided by Chris, I would suggest:

1. Transform your dataframe so all the columns you want to plot are contained in one column, using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Let's call the list of columns that you want to plot `columns_to_plot`

```py
df_for_plot = pd.melt(df, value_vars = columns_to_plot)
```

2. Use seaborn FacetGrid to plot it into separated plots:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_for_plot, col="variable")
g = g.map(plt.plot, "value")
```